# How to get substring from string containing newlines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, for-loop

I am trying to get substring from response string if the response length is greater than specified and loop through it. My code:

```
string response = //response from API
if (response.Length > 4096)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i += 4096)
    {
        string rplymsg = response.Substring(i, 4095);
        //other code using rplymsg 
    }
}
else
{
    //other code using response 
}
```

I have tried with [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) method and it is returning substring with specified length in debugging but actual substring length is greater than. (I verified by pasting substring in notepad++.)

[image: Length in QuickWatch-Debugging]

[image: Length in Notepad++]

I think the problem is because of `response` string and substring `rplymsg` contains new lines `\n`.
Is there any solution or better way to get count of string contains newlines, so that I can extract substring based on that length.

**Edit:**

For example:

```
String value = "Hi\nHello.";
int startIndex = 0;
int length = 4;
String substring = value.Substring(startIndex, length);
Console.WriteLine(substring);

// Output:
// Hi
// H

// Expected output:
// Hi\n
```

Comment: Why are you only getting 4095 character substrings instead of 4096?

Comment: If you want to extract data from HTML, then something like [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation) could make it much easier for you.

Comment: You are creating the new string within your for-loop. Is your logic correct? If you want to get the substring from start, you have to pass 0 as a first parameter.

Comment: Looks like notepad++ is counting 2 characters for each line break... You have difference of 37 characters between the length in code and the length in Notepad++ and you have total 38 lines in the Notepad++. I think you should rely on the length you get in the code and not rely on the Editor...

Comment: @phuzi The number of characters in the string `rplymsg`

Comment: @Chetan You're right, but how to get substring with newline ?

Comment: @SebastianSiemens I am using `i` for substring which will increment to 4096 on next iteration. So, I get string from 0 to 4095 in first iteration,  from 4096 to 8191 in second iteration and so on.

Comment: Are not getting the substring with this code? It is not clear what issue you are facing.. if you don't want to take the newline characters in count then you should first replace the newline characters with blank string and then do substring.

Comment: @Chetan Getting wrong substring count with this. What I am looking for is, loop through `response` string and get substring (4096 characters) one by one and passing it to somewhere else. Currently, `String.Substring` returning 4096 characters (not counting newlines) but actually it is 4132 (it containts newlines).

Comment: How do you say the count is wrong? Because you see it different in Notepad++? You should not consider the count shown in the editors... What happens when you pass the substring retrieved using current code to somewhere else? Are you facing issue while using this string somewhere else? What's the issue you are facing there?

Comment: @Chetan Yes, other method at somewhere (telegram server) throws error when it receives string greater than 4096 chars.

Comment: Do you not want to replace the newline characters in the original string and then do substring?

Comment: @Chetan No, I want to keep newline characters. Here substring length is 4096 characters `excluding newline characters`. I want to get substring length including newline characters.

Comment: I'm not sure that pasting into Notepad++ is a legitimate manner of checking the overall length. If it formats the data it will automatically add newline and or carriage return characters depending on the platform that it is running on. Check by switching on to view end of line symbols.

Comment: @ChrisBD I only added that image for people to understand question. I'm not relaying on N++. Please see my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after keeping the newline characters if a sting is less than you limiting size of 4096 then I think that you should split the string on that character, but instead of just `String.Substring(...)` consider using `String.Split(...)` as well processing the array of strings returned from it. e.g.:

```
    string response = "abcd\nefgh\nijklmnop\nrst\n";
    var maxLength = 5;
    var delimiter = new char[]{'\n'};
    var strings = response.Split(delimiter, StringSplitOptions.None); 
      

    foreach(var s in strings)
    {
        var delimited = s + '\n';//add newline as Split removes them from the result
        if(delimited.Length>maxLength)
        {
            var sub = delimited;
            while(sub.Length>maxLength)
            {
               var p = sub.Substring(0, maxLength-1);
               Console.WriteLine($"partial :{p}");
               sub = sub.Remove(0,maxLength-1);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"end :{sub}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"original :{delimited}");
        }
    }
```

This code isn't quite there as it will still output an extra message, but it should give you an idea (replacing `Console.WriteLine` with your processing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot of Notepad++ gives the explanation.

The orignal text within .Net uses line-feeds only, but your Notepad++ is configured (in the bottom right) to use Windows style (CR LF). This means, if you paste some text into that window (which can be proven by the fact, that your filename is *new 1* with a red icon) it will automatically be converted to the current style. And this means Notepad++ adds a CR before each LF and increases the length of the text.

Would you write your text from .Net into a file and open that file with Notepad++ you would see the true length. So the error is not within .Net or Visual Studio. It is your assumption to see the same in Notepad++ as in Visual Studio.

To fix this, right-click in the bottom right of Notepad++ on the Windows style and select  UNIX. Notepad++ will convert the file and you should see the same length as in Visual Studio (unless the original text mixes Windows and Unix style).

##### Update about last example

The example works completely as expected. You have this test string `Hi\nHello.`

If you take 4 characters from it, you get `Hi`, <kbd>LF</kbd> and `H`. When you print these four characters to the console, it will print out

```
Hi
H
```

The backslash within your code is an escape character that tells .Net that the next character is not a normal <kbd>n</kbd>. Instead it should be a line-feed which is a single character. Instead of that, you could also test `Hi\tHello`. This would mean to put a tabulator between the two words.

So you always have to really care about how the given text is visualized. If you watch a string variable within the watch window in Visual Studio, you see something like `Hi\nHello` to visualize whitespace characters, but if you click on the spy glass, you see the text without the `\n` but with a real line-break.

Comment: Can you please help me with my edited example at last?

Comment: @HarshadRaval Updated my answer.

Comment: I'm processing that substring at somewhere else and they are treating `Hi\nHello` as 9 characters. How to deal with it?

Comment: Then the question would be, what do *they* in their code?